# How to make a test function using pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I don't know how to make test function. 
I have this function

```
import pytest

def added(a, b, c):
    d = b + c
    e = a + c
    f = a + b
    return (d, e, f)

added(4,6,7)
```

How I can make a test_function for this function.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def test_added():
    assert added(4, 6, 7) == (13, 11, 10)
```

Then execute your test function. If all test are correct, you should get something like:

```
1 passed in x.xx seconds
```

Check the [docs](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html#getstarted) for more help.